# What's the best way to share the output between Github Actions reusable workflows?

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

I have a bunch of Github Actions that require exactly the same init process. I decided to implement a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows), but it turned out that the data is not shared between workflows.

I managed to solve that issue using `actions/cache`. I simply cache all the files with `path: '**/**'`, but I have a feeling that it's not an optimal approach. It doesn't feel like `actions/cache` was meant to be used for sharing the entire build directory. It was rather designed for sharing things like `node_modules` or other generated files to save processing time.

The solution provided below works, but it feels hacky. I wonder is there a better solution that would not require caching (I know I could use [artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) but it also doesn't feel right).

That's what I ended up with:

```yaml
# ./.github/workflows/init.yml

name: init
on: workflow_call
jobs:
  init:
    name: Init
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: '**/**' # Cache all files
          key: build-files-{{ github.sha }} # makes the key unique for each commit

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

      - name: Install Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          always-auth: true
          node-version: 12.x
          cache: 'npm'
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          scope: '@my-company-namespace'

      - name: Install NPM packages
        run: npm install
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}

      - name: Download translations
        run: npm run translations
        env:
          I18N_PROJECT_ID: ${{secrets.I18N_PROJECT_ID}}
          I18N_API_KEY: ${{secrets.I18N_API_KEY}}
```

```yaml
# ./.github/workflows/linter.yml

name: Linter
on: [push]
jobs:
  init:
    secrets: inherit
    uses: ./.github/workflows/init.yml # re-use the init.yml workflow
  linter:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs: [init]
    steps:
      - name: Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: '**/**' # restore cached files
          key:  build-files-{{ github.sha }}

      - name: Linter
        run: npm run lint
```

Comment: Note that by using caching, you might not be able to restore the files, because the cache was full. Better upload an artifact. However, I'd also question if it's really worth to create a reusable workflow here instead of just inlining the checkout, setup-node (which npm caching) etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "inlining the checkout, setup-node, etc"? Do you mean to copy/paste that bit to every workflow? If so then that's what I'm trying to avoid as it's pretty repetitive.

Comment: Yes, I meant copy :)

Comment: Following what **rethab** said, you could also create a local composite actions to reuse the same steps and actions, without using a reusable workflow, and then uses this local action in each one of the workflow using those steps.